# Paper-input inside paper-dropdown-menu is not properly focused

Tags: polymer

I tried to add a paper-input inside a paper-dropdown-menu so that I can search for items in the dropdown menu. Like this,

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-menu>
    <paper-input label="Search"></paper-input>
    <paper-item>...</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu
```

I've also wrote some js to override the default behaviour of the paper-dropdown-menu so that when I click on the paper-input, the menu doesn't close.

Now the problem is that when I click on the paper-input, I actually cannot type in anything because it seems the paper-input is not focused, or it is focused but in a unexpected way like a normal paper-input. I have to press a 'tab' to actually be able to type in something.

Is anyone know why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Move the paper-input outside the paper-menu, into a new div under the paper-dropdown-menu with the class "dropdown-content"

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label='Fruit'>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-input label="Search"></paper-input>
    <paper-menu> 
      <paper-item>Apples</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Oranges</paper-item>      
    </paper-menu>
  </div>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Here's a working example:
https://jsbin.com/tirinibiso/edit?html,output
The [paper-dropdown-menu example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu) given by Polymer is there as well.

Comment: @li207 Could you please post your solution as to how you search for the items. I am doing something similar with checkboxes and would like to search for the checkbox too. I am also having difficulty making multiple selections of the checkboxes.